# Shortcut to open kde konsole at current location

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, shortcuts, konsole

How can I create a shortcut to open kde konsole at current location? For example, if I am in Download directory, I want the konsole to start from that location. Is it possible using a shortcut? I am using KDE 18.04

Comment: What do you mean by "KDE 18.04"? Is that Ubuntu with KDE or is that Kubuntu? Which file manager are you using?

Comment: its kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Press `Shift`+`F4`.

Comment: It works. Could you tell me what is the command that is run when I press `shift+F4`?

Comment: If I find out, I'll ping you.

Answer (score 0):

`F4` -> open [konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) in [dolphin](https://apps.kde.org/dolphin/)

`shift`+`F4` -> open [konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) in new window

Check [KDE UserBase Wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Configure Keyboard Shortcuts > Search for "Terminal".

The default shortcuts are:

Open external terminal window at current location: Shift+F4
Show integrated terminal at current location: F4